# What is the format of Express' req.params?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I've got a weird thing I'm running into with req.params while working with Express.  It works fine for calling the subordinate properties - e.g.: res.json(req.params.paramName); gives me the desired paramName value.  But when I tried to pass the entire res.params object to the client via res.json(req.params), I just get an empty array [] in the browser instead of the JSON object I was expecting.  (res.send gives the same result.)

Looking a bit deeper, I dumped req.params to the console:

```
console.dir(req.params);
```

and got this:

```
[ creator: '1', timeStart: '2', timeEnd: '3', dateDensity: '4' ]
```

wut?  Is that even syntactically possible in Javascript?
If req.params is a simple object like the Express code and documentation indicate, I should be getting:

```
{ creator: '1', timeStart: '2', timeEnd: '3', dateDensity: '4' }
```

An array like what I'm getting above should even be possible, should it?

I did some sanity checks and passed a couple of test objects to the console as well:

```
console.dir([{foo:1}, {arr:2}, {gog:3}, {blah:4}]);
console.dir({foo:1, arr:2, gog:3, blah:4});
```

and the console dump gives me:

```
[ { foo: 1 }, { arr: 2 }, { gog: 3 }, { blah: 4 } ]
{ foo: 1, arr: 2, gog: 3, blah: 4 }
```

So console.dir is working OK.

Lastly, I hardcoded a:

```
res.json({foo:1, arr:2, gog:3, blah:4});
```

into my Express code and the browser dutifully gives me:

```
{
  "foo": 1,
  "arr": 2,
  "gog": 3,
  "blah": 4
}
```

Am I smoking crack here?  What is going on with req.params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how v8 prints out arrays with string keys:

```
var myArr = [];
myArr.key = "oops";
```

Remember, `[] instanceof Object` is true.

`req.params` is an array, suggesting the possibility of positional params.

Comment: OK, I think that makes sense - req.params is defined as an array but the actual parameters are stored on it via standard object properties, correct?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the bit about the positional parameters though.  I thought JS params were passed positonally by default.

Comment: Js function parameters have no connection to express request parameters

Comment: It was unclear to me in your response whether you were talking about using the array as an alternate (unused?) way for Express to preserve the original order of the parameters in the URL or as some sort of generalized parameter passing construct.  It seems like an unnecessarily convoluted way to pass the parameters.

Comment: @DanHeidel: From the documentation, I just found that numeric (ie positional) keys are used to represent regex captures used in URL routing.